# ”jQuery is not defined" Angular & JavaScript, Avaya

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have an Angular projects which uses the AvayaClientSDK (basicalliy three JS Files). I somehow imported the AvayaClientSDK JS File in my component and it says "jQuery is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

```
var S = jQuery;
```

That line is expecting jQuery to be defined at this point.

The first rule of Angular development is we don't use jQuery.

But if you must then try adding a jQuery include in your index.html file.

Comment: Sorry im new to Angular, how exactly do i include it?